# How to dynamically loop columns when `select where like` till result has only one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table test(col1 int, col2 varchar,col3 date);

insert into test values (1,'abc','2015-09-10');

insert into test values (1,'abd2','2015-09-11');

insert into test values (21,'xyz','2015-09-12');

insert into test values (2,'xyz','2015-09-13');

insert into test values (3,'tcs','2015-01-15');

insert into test values (3,'tcs','2016-01-18');
```

What I want:

```
if
select col1,col2 from test where col1 LIKE '%3%';
has more than 1 rows,then

if
select col1,col2 from test where col1 LIKE '%3%' AND col2 LIKE '%t%';
has more than 1 rows,then

select col1,col2 from test where col1 LIKE '%3%' AND col2 LIKE '%t%' AND col3 LIKE '%2016%';
```

Another case:

```
if
select col1,col2 from test where col1 LIKE '%1%';
has more than 1 rows,then

if
select col1,col2 from test where col1 LIKE '%1%' AND col2 LIKE '%a%';
has more than 1 rows,then

select col1,col2 from test where col1 LIKE '%1%' AND col2 LIKE '%a%' AND col3 LIKE '%2015%';

if all columns looped,output regardless the number of rows
```

How to do it in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to dynamically loop columns when `select where like` till result has only one row?

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select col1, col2
from test
where col1 like '%3%' 
order by (col1 LIKE '%3%')::int + (col2 LIKE '%t%')::int + (col3 LIKE '%2016%')::int desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Does this answer cove `another case`?

Comment: @kittygirl . . . Your question -- which is boldly stated in the title -- is about returning one row.  To be honest, I don't know what "another case" is supposed to be.  It contradicts the question.